# Startup a Servlet before loading app context

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet which is bundled as part of my application. I want to be able to configure Tomcat or Spring to load this servlet at boostrap before the application context is finally initialize.

I am doing this because - I am using the servlet to do some initial enviroment checking and file loading before the actual context gets fired.

Do anyone knows a good of doing this?

I have added servlet definition like this;

```
    <servlet> 
            <servlet-name>init-class</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>package.initClass</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet>
```

This only gets fired after the app context has finished loading.

Comment: which appcontext are you referring to?  Another servlet?

Comment: I am referring to Spring application context which holds all my bean wiring.

Comment: and what do you need to do there? And what is not fired - the init() method of the servlet.. ?

Comment: How is this appcontext wired up? Using a `DispatcherServlet`, or a `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: everything gets fired ok! my problem is the order in which they gets fired. I want my initClass.java first fired to do some basic file loading and enviroment checks before the spring context gets fired.

Comment: appcontext wired using ContextLoaderListener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place this initialization logic into [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) instead of servlet and declare it in `web.xml` as

```
<listener><listener-class>YourListenerClass</listener-class></listener>
```

Also, if your Spring context is loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`, your listener should be declared in `web.xml` before it, since listeners are fired in declaration order.

Comment: Is there a way to run the code before context is initialized? ServletContextListener has 2 method. contextInitialized method which runs after context is initialized and contextDestroyed which runs after context is destroyed. I want a method which runs right after context params are initialized and before Spring listeners start up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Listner](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Lifecycle_Listeners) is what you're looking for